# Backup Exec 2010 on x86 Media server protecting Exchange 2007

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange-2007, backupexec

I'm using BE 2010 to backup Exchange 2007.  The Media server is Win2k8 x86.  In order to use granular recovery options, I need to install the MAPI CDO and Exchange Management Console on the Media server.

Are there any problems with setting up the x86 version of the EMC on the Media server to accomplish this?  I've looked through the admin guide and can't find anything saying I can't do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no problem, the Exchange management tools for Exchange 2007 comes in two versions 64 and 32BIT.

So you can safely install the Exchange Mgmt. tools 32BIT on your Media Server.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=44c66ad6-f185-4a1d-a9ab-473c1188954c#filelist

just select the management tools for installation

Comment: +1 - Works just fine.